# Integrating a power series

Tags: analysis

I am not a pure mathematician, so I would appreciate some help from people who have done analysis! Can we have some function which is analytic (which I believe just means expressible as a power series) but the term by term integral does not converge or somehow goes wrong? If so, what are the requirements for the function so that this does not happen?

---

Also, suppose we don't do the integration term by term, then would it always be true that an integral is well-defined/exists where the power series of the function "works"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power series $\sum_i a_ix^i$ has radius of convergence at least $r$ whenever $a_nr^n$ has at most sub-exponential growth as $n\to\infty$, that is if $a_nr^n=o(\lambda^n)$ for every $\lambda>1$. Taking a formal primitive gives $\sum_{i>0} \frac{a_{i-1}}ix^i$, and it is easy to see that $\frac{a_{n-1}}nr^n=o(\lambda^n)$ if and only if $a_nr^n=o(\lambda^n)$, so the radius of convergence is unchanged by taking a primitive.